How do you set formatting rules for C# spread operator in Visual Studio?
I know this is probably not the right place to ask this, but I doubt I'd find an answer somewhere else.
Visual Studio 17.9.5 will, by default, format the following snippet as such
int[] arr = [1, 2];
int[] biggerArr = [0, .. arr];


but I would really like to have it not add the space between the spread operator and the variable name as such
int[] arr = [1, 2];
int[] biggerArr = [0, ..arr];

However, I don't seem to find any relevant setting for this under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Spacing. Does anyone have any idea what setting controls this? Another interesting thing is that this is considered proper formatting by Visual Studio
int[] arr = [1, 2];
int[] biggerArr = [
    0, ..arr];

EDIT: Submitted a Developer Community request

Note that this is not the range operator, it's a collection expression with a spread operator.

Currently - no as far as I can see. Even rider which has one for  similar slice operator does not have it.

We don't post images of code here.

Thanks for raising the feedback ticket, I'm also interested in this. It got closed as dupe of github issue https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/71219 which itself is closed as by-design, although there is some discussion ongoing.

Seems there isn't an option for this and there isn't a plan to implement this as discussed here.

Unfortunately, there is no such option list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options.
You could suggest a feature on Developer Community and post the link here.

Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question with the request link.
